# android check if EditText is empty and then avoid dialog from canceling

Tags: android, dialog

Hey in my app for android, I am trying to make a dialog, with a EditText. My problem with my code is, if my EditTex is empty the app will not work. Therefore I am trying to check if the EditText is empty and prevent the dialog from canceling if the EditText is empty.
Thanks in advance

Here is the code:

```
private void AdPoint() {        
 final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     LinearLayout linearlayout= new LinearLayout(this);
     linearlayout.setOrientation(1);         
        final EditText point_field = new EditText(this);
        final String point_field_string = point_field.getText().toString();
        point_field.setImeOptions(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        point_field.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);

        linearlayout.addView(point_field);

        alert.setView(linearlayout);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setTitle(playername1string);
        alert.setMessage(R.string.how_many_point);

        point_field.setHint("10");
        playername1.setText(playername1string);


        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.plus, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


                if (point_field_string.matches("")) {                   
                    //My code, if the EditText is not emty                      
                    return;
                }else {
                point_field.setText("0");

                }



                        }

        });
        alert.show();  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
if (point_field_string.matches("")) {                   
                    //My code, if the EditText is not emty                      
                    return;
                }
  else {
                point_field.setText("0");

                }
```

to:

```
if(point_field_string.getText()!=null){
if (point_field_string.getText().toString().length()>0) {                   
   //My code, if the EditText is not emty                      
   return;
}
    else {
                point_field.setText("0");

                }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this...

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(point_field_string)){
  // code to handle if field is empty
}else{
  // code to handle if field is non-empty
}
```